# Disabling Indentation and Auto Closing Brackets in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Right now Notepad++ is automatically adding closing brackets as well as automatically indenting my code. (PHP)

It's doing this differently from how the code I'm working with is indented.

Is there a way I can do the following?

- Disable automatic indentation where it changes the indentation, but keep the indentation where it continues the existing?
  (so if I am indented 3 places and press enter, I'll be indented 3 places on the new line, but if I open a bracket, I'll STILL be indented 3 places)
- Disable automatic bracket closing entirely

(I don't have any options under the auto-complete section checked).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why, but the settings in Auto-Complete were the culprit.  Everything was unchecked, but checking them, closing the options, going back in and unchecking it (setting it back to how it was when I originally looked) solved it and it's behaving correctly now.

(Best guess is the UI was not reflecting the actual settings somehow.)

Comment: Nice troubleshooting! That's definitely a bizarre situation, but I suspect your guess is right.

Answer (score 4):

First of all the automatic bracket completion is easy. Just go to **Settings >> Preferences >> Auto Completion** and uncheck the parentheses, brackets, and curly brackets from the list as shown in the following picture. This will stop auto completion of those brackets.

[image: Uncheck braces]

Second for the auto indentation, you will have to use a workaround. If you go into **Settings >> Preferences >> MISC.** you will find an option for auto indent. However in my experience that will not stop auto indentation for php. The workaround is a plugin called **NppAutoIndent**. You can download this from the plugin manager (**Plugins >> Plugin Manager >> Show Plugin Manager**). After you download it, go to **Plugins >> NppAutoIndent** and check **Previous Line** and make sure **Ignore Language** is unchecked. See the pitcure below for clarity.

[image]

I hope this helps you and if not feel free to comment! God Bless and have a great day!

Comment: As I mentioned in my initial post, the catch is, none of those settings are on.  Everything under "Auto-Completion" is unchecked.

Comment: It worked for me so I am not exactly sure what your problem is.

Comment: Likewise.  I went through all the usual options and as far as I can see, it should not be doing what it is.  I'm guessing there some additional setting I'm missing.